# nmake: file not found (error U1052)

Tags: c, makefile, nmake

I am trying to use nmake to build a program I downloaded [(source)](https://sourceforge.net/projects/rsaref/). The program is old (1994) but I need to build it for research purposes.

As I'm using windows, I'm calling nmake whilst in the \install\dos\ directory, and receiving:

> makefile(62) : fatal error U1052: file '..\source\targets.mak' not
>   found.

I've checked, and targets.mak does exist in 'X:\Desktop\rsaref\source\targets.mak' so I tried the command:

> nmake /F X:\Desktop\rsaref\source\targets.mak

But I now receive the error:

> NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'desc.c'

I have no clue what i'm doing here as i've never used makefiles before, and as this program is highly depreciated, i'm struggling to find advice on how to use it.

Comment: Show the makefile.

Comment: From the sourceforge-site: "Description: This is the ancient and highly depreciated RSA refrence code." <- Ancient code often depends on ancient build environments and is therefore hard to compile

Comment: You can try this: enter the directory "install" and type `nmake /F dos\makefile`

Comment: @Ctx This gives me a new error:  "LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'rsaref.lib;' 
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'if' : return code '0x49d' "

Comment: "I'm calling nmake whilst in the \install\dos\ directory" It seems that you haven't read `doc\readme.txt`